# Duck Typing vs Type Juggling

Tags: javascript, php

In some literature, I have read that the variable in Javascript supports Duck Typing and variable in PHP supports Type Juggling. I have little bit confusing about it cause it seems similar when declare variable in Javascript and PHP.  What is the main difference between these terminology?

Comment: Those are arguably superfluous concepts, don't get too hung up on them when learning to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mixing stuff up: type juggling, as explained by the PHP documentation, is about the flexibility to automatically **cast** values to a better suiting type when needed. For example, the following works fine:

```
$a = "42";     // now $a is a string
$a = $a + 42;  // now $a is an integer
$a = $a + 23;  // now $a is still an integer
$a = $a + 1.3; // now $a is a float
```

On the other hand, duck typing is about the question how an object itself behaves:

> If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

If an object has the proper methods, we can assume that it is of a specific type. If it contains the methods `quack` or `swim` like a duck does, it can be a duck. Specifically for JS, there are good examples at [Example of Javascript Duck Typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12762550) - there is no type casting involved here