# Testing if a method returns an Promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise

In angularjs, while testing a service, I want to check if the returned object is an Promise.

Right now I am doing the following -

```
 obj.testMethod()
        .should.be.instanceOf($q.defer());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if an object is a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746304/how-do-i-tell-if-an-object-is-a-promise)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at line 248 in the source for $q (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L248) there isn't really a check you can do thats definite. This would be your best bet

```
var deferred = method();

if(angular.isObject(deferred) && 
   angular.isObject(deferred.promise) && 
   deferred.promise.then instanceof Function && 
   deferred.promise["catch"] instanceof Function && 
   deferred.promise["finally"] instanceof Function){
   //This is a simple Promise
}
```

If the promise was actually a function where you could use `new Promise()` then you would be able to use `promise instanceof Promise`, however it's an object so it doesn't have any special identifiers, the only things you can test are their properties.

**EDIT**:

To test for a "`HttpPromise`" then you can add on checks for `error` and `success` which are defined in the `$http` service (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L726):

```
var promise = $http(...);

if(angular.isObject(promise) && 
   promise.then instanceof Function && 
   promise["catch"] instanceof Function && 
   promise["finally"] instanceof Function && 
   promise.error instanceof Function && 
   promise.success instanceof Function){
   //This is a HttpPromise
}
```

**EXTRA**:

If you notice $http doesn't actually return `deferred`, it returns the straight promise, if you follow the calls it's actually returns `$q.when(...)` with a couple of functions added to it. You can see that `$q.when` doesn't return `deferred`, rather it returns `$q.deferred().promise`, so in turn `$http(...)` would never be `$q.deferred()`

Also, if you were to run the test you had posted I would expect you to get this error:

`TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>`

Comment: The above code still doesn't check for `HttpPromise` which is not really $q promise. Right?

Comment: Pretty sure they are the same arent they? It returns $q.when with success and error added to it promise declared: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L707 , promise modified to add success & error: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L726,

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the source code. This is definitely useful.

Comment: The great thing with open source projects is that you can drill right down and see how everything is happening. What framework are you using for testing? Is that a real method or psuedo code? I would assume a new "instance" of `$q.deffered();` would have a bit missing, esp the success and error functions. Meaning they wouldn't "equal" so to say, however they would still both be promises

Comment: Its pseudo code and I am using mocha. So I should basically test if its a promise and then check if it has `success` and `error` methods?

Comment: shouldn't that be deferred, not deffered?

Answer (score 12):

Testing if an object is a promise is simple:

```
return !!obj.then && typeof obj.then === 'function';
```

That's it. If an object has the `then` method, it's a promise.

It looks like angular's $q doesn't have anything to differentiate it from other kind of promises.

Comment: This is the more correct approach in my opinion, as $q itself will treat anything with a `.then` as a promise.

Comment: Why the downvote ? For most purposes it looks like the most usable answer.

Comment: Maybe also check if `obj.then.length === 2` after first verifying it's a function. A promise's `.then()` method should have two formal parameters (a resolve handler and a reject handler) and the `.length` property of a function should return the number of formal parameters said function accepts.

Comment: @idbehold that's probably not the best idea - consider an Angular $q or Q promise or a jQuery deferred that have 3 parameters (one for progression).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum okay, `obj.then.length >= 2`.

Comment: @Florian Margaine what is mean by "!!" in staring of code ?

Comment: -1 No, this isn't true. Why was discussed in the chat. A more formal version is available here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ecf9ae41e58e8d9a9d6de8ecdb3c340f

Comment: I like this answer, but how about: `return obj && object.then && typeof obj.then==='function';`? Its null/undefined safe and it doesn't bother to cast obj.then to a Boolean since it will just evaluate as truthy anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could mock `$http` and have it return some object you create. Then you can check whether your service returns that object.

Comment: the `testMethod` returns a HttpPromise, with success and error methods. I dont want to loose them.

Comment: If you check that (the fact that the object has a success and an error method), is that not sufficient?

Comment: For the moment I am doing exactly what you mentioned. But it would be great If I could test via `instanceOf` method. Don't you think so?

Comment: It depends on what you think is the API of your service. Does it return "a promise" or does it return an object that has a then and a success and and error function. And what is the definition of "a promise"? You're not writing code in a typed language, that's why it's hard to test for the type of the returned object... Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379529/duck-typing-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I was working with callbacks, I needed a CTA on click event to fire a function and determine what type of callback was fired, here is some simple examples.

```js
let fn = function () { alert('A simple function') };

let cta = fn();

console.log(cta instanceof Promise);

// logs false
```

New Promise Example

```js
let fn = function () {

    return new Promise(function (accept, reject) {

        accept();

        // reject();

    });

};

let cta = fn();

if(cta instanceof Promise) {

    cta.then(function () {

        alert('I was a promise');

    });

}
```

Axios Example 1

```js
let fn = function () {

   return axios.get('/user');

}

let cta = fn();

if(cta instanceof Promise) {

    cta.then(function () {

        alert('I was a promise from axios');

    });

}

// Triggers alert('I was a promise from axios');
```

Axios Example 2

```js
let fn = function () {

   return axios.get('/user').then(response => {
       console.log('user response', response.data);
   });

}

let cta = fn();

if(cta instanceof Promise) {

    cta.finally(function () {

        alert('I was a final promise from axios');

    });

}

// Triggers alert('I was a final promise from axios');
```