# Looking for the name of the following principle

Tags: javascript, function, methods, design-principles

I know there's a 'methodology' where the developer should write such functions, that the return value is always of the same type. So, say we have a function what tends to return an array, and something unwanted happens, like the argument is invalid, in such cases we won't return `null`, instead we return an empty array `[]`. Then the *user* of the method can be sure, that the returned value will be an array.

I can't remember to the name of the principle, can you help me out please?

Thanks

### Example

Instead:

```
function(arg) {
  var res;
  if (arg) {
    return ['example'];
  }
  return res;
}
```

We must set a default value according to the principle:

```
function(arg) {
  var res = [];
  if (arg) {
    res = ['example'];
  }
  return res;
}
```

Note, that in the first case, there's a race condition in the return value (undefined/array), while in the latter case, we return with an array.

Comment: I think, neither of them. But thanks for the suggestions. ;)

Comment: Do you mean [Duck Typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379529/duck-typing-in-javascript)?

Comment: Looks like method chaining, except there methods return `this`, not an arbitrary object of the right type - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: You could also be describing (one part of) a [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Comment: @chridam nope, duck typing means if something quacks, and have feathers and etc.. then it can be considered as a duck. My 'problem' is different than this.

Comment: See also [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

Comment: Here's some advice that refers to this idiom as "avoiding in band error indicators": http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2133373&seqNum=5. I don't know if I've seen anything more precise than that, and I've seen this practice recommended by people whom I would expect to know the term if there were one.

Comment: @Eric i was not looking for this, but thanks for the link;) Btw i had the opportunity to learn about DbC at the univ. and wrote some Eiffel code back then, and i found it very interesting, good stuff :)

Comment: _"Note, that in the first case, there's a race condition"_ - No there isn't. That's not what ["race condition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) means.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the below, is done to avoid performing null checks in the calling method. This is done **not only** for array types but for all the object types to handle null/undefined returns.

```
function(arg) {
  var res = []; // initialization of an object
  if (arg) {
    res = ['example'];
  }
  return res;
}
```

For example,

when you call the above function, there is no possibility that the returned value would be null or undefined. This eliminates adding a

`if((var x = function(arg)) != null)` check in the calling method.

The closest Design pattern you can relate to is the Null Object pattern in java.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/null_object_pattern.htm

Comment: Thanks, yea i know, thats why i edited the original question with an example. I'm more and more convinced that my memory is malfunctioning at this one :)

Comment: hmm.. so you knew about the Null object pattern too ?

Comment: Nope, i didn't, but i knew the side effects of my example, what you mentioned in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Then the user of the method can be sure, that the returned value will be an array

Sounds like [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Although, even in a typesafe language you could easily return `null` if you document the return type to be [nullable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type).