# Calling a constructor with missing arguments, within a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple list view which displays items, with the help of Knockout. A set of '*Things*' are hard coded into an array and Knockout lists them at page load. It works fine so far.

Now, I wish to add a new function: newFunc(). A new item will be created in the function with a property, but without a name. The item can be added to the list later, if the user wishes. A name can be given to the item by the user then.

**Q**: In this situation, how can I (or can I) use the constructor function '*Item*' to create a new item, in the new function? The '*Item*' function requires an argument 'item', yet in the new function, I cannot pass an argument, since the new item is being created and a name is not given. How should I think and code differently to achieve the functionality described?

Any help and tips would be appreciated.

// HTML //

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: itemList'>
    <li data-bind='text: name'></li>
</ul>
```

// Script //

```
var Things = [
    { name: 'name1', property: 'prop1' },
    { name: 'name2', property: 'prop2' },
    ...
];

var Item = function(item) {
    this.name = item.name;
    this.property = item.property;
};

// The new function in Question
var aNewItem;
newFunc = function() {
    // I'd like to create an 'Item' with a given property, but w/o a name.
    aNewItem = new Item(); // ???
    aNewItem.property = 'propertyN'; // **Edit**: also a variable set by user or callback.
};

var viewModel = function {
    self = this;
    self.itemList = ko.observableArray();
    Things.forEach(function(item) {
        self.itemList.push(new Item(item));
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Instead of creating the item and then setting the properties, can't you just gather the properties, then call the constructor? Otherwise, you'll have to remove the `item` parameter and set the properties explicitly after instantiation.

Comment: Yes, it certainly can be a solution, I think. Collect data into a variable or an array and use it later as needed with the constructor. Thanks for a good suggestion! I don't think removing the `item` parameter might not be the best solution, since I am looking for something scalable and reading in data from an array `Things`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object that only has a `property` property in it.

```
aNewItem = new Item({
  property: 'propertyN'
});
```

Comment: It seems like a very simple solution. Thank you very much. In this case, does the `name` property of `aNewItem` set as a `null` value, automatically? (Is there any documentation, which I can read about the usage of a  constructor like this?)

Comment: @Yui In JS, you have two "null-like" values. `null` and `undefined` ([see MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)). By default, a variable (or property) has the value of `undefined` unless it's explicitly given another value. As for how this constructor works, all that you're doing is giving it an object with the properties you require. [If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379721/371184)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options (in order of best practice I adopt):

#### Using default options in the constructor

You can specify default options for your constructor's properties by using the `||` (or) operator in the assignment (= if value before the `||` is falsy, assign the value after). If you have an object as parameter (which is the easiest), you can re-assign item to an empty object if it is not passed, which makes testing for its properties easier.

```
var Item = function(item) {
    var item = item || {};
    this.name = item.name || '';
    this.property = item.property || 'propertyN';
};
```

#### Using default options in the caller (newFunc)

Although I think it is cleaner to have default values as previously shown, it is also possible to specify them in the function that invokes the constructor:

```
newFunc = function() {
    aNewItem = new Item({property: 'propertyN'});
};
```

Or if you specified defaults in the constructor, your function will work just as well in its current state.

#### Adding only properties specified by the item param

You can also choose to add all properties that are given in item with a `for..in` loop. Disclaimer: I would not advise this as it makes using a constructor pretty pointless.

```
var Item = function(item) {
    var item = item || {};
    for (var prop in item) 
      this[prop] = item[prop];
};
```

You could then do:

```
newFunc = function() {
    aNewItem = new Item({property: 'propertyN', foo: 'foo'});
    bNewItem = new Item(); 
    console.log(aNewItem.foo); // 'foo'
    console.log(bNewItem['whatever']); // undefined
};
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting various solution options. Your answer is very informative! When using a default option constructor (the first option), what cases are classified as a 'false'? A null?

Comment: @Yui, for example null, false, undefined, a zero-width string (''), a string with '0', the number 0, a zero-width array.. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) also lists some. Basically everything that will return `true` when you do `myFalsyValue == false` (not 3 equals, only in non-strict comparison).